# Creating a comment box html form with perl processing script

Tags: html, perl

I currently have a script named "test.pl" that does a variety of things and prints out HTML code to view on a webpage. One of the things I want it to do, is allow the user to type in a comment, and select which type of comment it is and the processing form of the comment box will append the comment into a file. I am not sure if I am doing this right because it doesn't seem to be working as I'm getting some errors.. here are the snippets of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);  # Use CGI modules that let people read data passed from a form

#Initiate comment processing
&ReadParse(%in);
if ($in("comment") && $in("type") ! == "") {
    $comment = $in("comment");
    $type = $in("type");
    WritetoFile($comment,$type);
}

sub WritetoFile {
    my $input = shift;
    my $type = shift;
    my $file = "$type" . "_comment.txt";
    open (my $fh, '>>', $file) or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";
    print $fh "$input\n";
    close $fh
}
```

The form I am using is this:

```
<FORM ACTION=test.pl METHOD=POST>
Comment:
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="comment" LENGTH=60>
<P>
Select Type
<SELECT NAME ="type">
<OPTION SELECTED> Animal
<OPTION> Fruit
<OPTION> Vegetable
<OPTION> Meat
<OPTION> Other
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Submit"></FORM
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work or even improve the process I am doing would be greatly appreciated!I would prefer to keep the processing script and the script that does the rest of my subs to be the same script (test.pl) unless this is something I have to keep separate

Comment: You don't need to keep them separate - `POST`ed data comes in on `STDIN`. However, CGI is deprecated, so isn't recommended.

Comment: Is there anything you recommend doing instead?

Comment: @EvanMiller There are several alternatives with demos in the [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) documentation.

Comment: I quite like mojolicious - I've been fiddling with it a bit. It takes a little getting to grips with initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bizarre mixture of old- and new-style Perl. You're using the cgi-lib compatibility layer in CGI.pm and calling its ReadParse() function using the (unnecessary since 1994) leading ampersand. On the other hand, you're using three-arg open() and lexical filehandles. I'd be interested to hear how you developed that style.

Your problem comes from your (mis-)handling of the %in hash. Your call to ReadParse() puts all of the CGI parameters into the hash, but you're using the wrong syntax to get the values out of the hash. Hash keys are looked up using braces (`{ ... }`), not parentheses (`( ... )`).

You also have some confusion over your boolean equality operators. `!=` is used for numeric comparisons. You want `ne` for string comparisons.

You probably wanted something like:

```
ReadParse(%in);
if ($in{comment} ne "" and $in{type} ne "") {
    $comment = $in{comment};
    $type = $in{type};
    WritetoFile($comment,$type);
}
```

Your `$comment` and `$type` variables are unnecessary as you can pass the hash lookups directly into your subroutine.

```
WritetoFile($in{comment}, $in{type});
```

Finally, as others have pointed out, learning CGI in 2014 is like learning to use a typewriter - it'll still work, but people will think you're rather old-fashioned. Look at [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for some more modern approaches.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! I did realize I had the braces wrong, I totally forgot about using ne instead of != so thank you for that. You are right, that is is old-fashioned, it is just something I have seen around from other scripts I'm using as a sort of guide/template. But I do think I should adapt newer practices so I will look at this alternative. I really appreciate all that info!